# Why won't colorkey or setalpha work on my code in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, transparency

I am creating a game in pygame and I am trying to get the images to have their white backgrounds transparent, I did my research and tried set_colorkey and convert_alpha. Could someone tell me why this isn't working.

```
class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self,player):
    super().__init__()

    if player == 1:
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Megaman.png')
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)

    elif player == 2:
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Megaman2.png')
        self.image.convert_alpha()
```

The images are of Megaman with a white background. They are png images.
The color white is

```
white = 255,255,255)
```

and this is the image of megaman:
[image of megaman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcTSo.png)

Comment: The purpose of `convert_alpha` is to improve the blit performance of images that already have a transparent background. If your image has a white background, then `set_colorkey(white)` should make it transparent provided the background color and your `white` variable are really the same color. Add your image and the `white` variable, so that we can test the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying to make a `.png` file of your pictures without a white background, as this would allow you to use `convert_alpha()`. I have found more success with that then `setcolorkey`

If you wish to remove the white backround of `Megaman2.png`, I suggest you don't use `convert_alpha`, as it does not remove color.

***EDIT:***
Did you write your code as `white = 255,255,255)`? That would cause a problem as you forgot a parentheses.